# Checking dates with php and drupal

Tags: php, loops, date, drupal

I am trying to revise some code that someone else created, but I am having difficulty due to my lack of much php experience and especially because it is handling dates entered in fields on a drupal site.

Currently, php is checking if there are *any* blog posts ($event_items) created in the drupal interface and to run accordingly. What I want to happen is for event_item posts to appear on the site if their start date is in the future. If it is not, the event_item post does not show, and if *none* of the events are in the future, show a message.

Currently, if there are no event_items in the future, none of the posts will show up on the site but the message won't show up either because the posts are still archived in the drupal interface.

All attempts I've made have to edit the code has either solved the issue but bugged out some other functionality on the page, or cause the messages to show up for every event_item post that is in the past.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
unset($content['field_events_event_items']['#prefix']);
unset($content['field_events_event_items']['#suffix']);
$all_events = array();
$event_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_events_event_items');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($event_items); $i++) {
        $value = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_events_event_items', $event_items[$i]);
        $field_collection = $value['entity']['field_collection_item'][key($value['entity']['field_collection_item'])];
        $start_time[] = $field_collection['field_event_date_time']['#items'][0]['value'];
        if (date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($field_collection['field_event_date_time']['#items'][0]['value'])) >= date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
            $all_events[date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($field_collection['field_event_date_time']['#items'][0]['value']))][] = $field_collection;
        }
    }
if (isset($event_items[0])) {
?>
    <div class="panel-group" id="event-listings" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php

    ksort($all_events);
    $prev_date = '';
    foreach ($all_events as $date => $date_events) {
        if (date('F Y', strtotime($date)) != $prev_date) {
?>
    <h3 class="filter-group-heading"><?=(date('Y') == date('Y', strtotime($date)) ? date('F', strtotime($date)) : date('F Y', strtotime($date)))?></h3>
<?php
        }
        foreach ($date_events as $i => $date_event) {
            print render($date_event);  
        }
        $prev_date = date('F Y', strtotime($date));         
    }
?>
        </div>
<?php   
} else {
?>      
        <div>
                <p>Sorry, there are no scheduled events coming up.</p>
        </div>
<?php   
}
?>
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here seems to be the `if (isset($event_items[0])) {` line.  Try changing it to `if ($all_events) {`

Here's a cleaned-up version with more descriptive variable names, and less code duplication, that you can examine if you need some inspiration.

```
<?php
unset($content['field_events_event_items']['#prefix']);
unset($content['field_events_event_items']['#suffix']);

$timeFormat                 = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$eventsWithFutureStartDates = array();
$allEventsUnfilteredByDate  = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_events_event_items');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($allEventsUnfilteredByDate); $i++) {
    $value = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_events_event_items', $allEventsUnfilteredByDate[$i]);

    $field_collection = $value['entity']['field_collection_item'][key($value['entity']['field_collection_item'])];

    $eventDateTime         = $field_collection['field_event_date_time']['#items'][0]['value'];
    $eventDateTimeUnix     = strtotime($eventDateTime);
    $eventDateTimeMidnight = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $eventDateTimeUnix);
    $itemIsInFuture        = ($eventDateTimeMidnight >= date($timeFormat));

    if ($itemIsInFuture) {
        $eventsWithFutureStartDates[date($timeFormat, $eventDateTimeUnix)][] = $field_collection;
    }
}

if ($eventsWithFutureStartDates) {
    ?>
    <div class="panel-group" id="event-listings" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <?php

        ksort($eventsWithFutureStartDates);
        $prev_date = '';
        foreach ($eventsWithFutureStartDates as $date => $date_events) {
            if (date('F Y', strtotime($date)) != $prev_date) {
                ?>
                <h3 class="filter-group-heading"><?=(date('Y') == date('Y', strtotime($date)) ? date('F', strtotime($date)) : date('F Y', strtotime($date)))?></h3>
                <?php
            }
            foreach ($date_events as $i => $date_event) {
                print render($date_event);
            }
            $prev_date = date('F Y', strtotime($date));
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <div>
        <p>Sorry, there are no scheduled events coming up.</p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Nate, thank you so much. This clarifies things immensely... obviously using strtotime to get the unix timestamp is something I wasn't quite grasping. I'm a little confused about what happens in the "if itemIsInFuture" condition. Is the concept: "If the array item is in the future, place it in the futureEvents array, which becomes the new field_collection array." Is that the right ballpark? It essentially filters out all past events from the field_collection? Anyway, if you can clear that up I would be _even more_ appreciative but once again I thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Yep, you're basically right.  And just to be clear: the version I provided is functionally identical to the code you posted (except for the single line change I suggested).  Here's how I understood the (new) code's logic:

(1) Fetch all the events and store them in the `$allEventsUnfilteredByDate` array.
(2) Iterate over each one, and determine if its date is in the future.  If it is, add it to the `$eventsWithFutureStartDates` array.
(3) Once we're done with that `for` loop, we can disregard the `$allEventsUnfilteredByDate` array.  (4) Were any future events located?

Comment: (4a) YES: Print each one, and ensure they appear below the proper date heading.  Note that as we're doing this iteration (in the second `for` loop), the data that was originally saved as `$field_collection` in the first loop is now available again as the `$date_event` variable. (4b) NO: Display "Sorry, there are no scheduled events coming up."